# Parse pylint result to extract score?

Tags: bash, sed

I am building a github CI using action and I was able to run pylint and write a message to PR with the result.  However, I want to parse the exact score so I can fail the action if it's bellow a certain threshold, here is my relevant code:

```
- name: Lint with pylint
  working-directory: ./
  run: |
    echo '${{ steps.files.outputs.files_updated }} ${{ steps.files.outputs.files_created }}'
    pip install pylint
    OUTPUT=$(pylint ${{ steps.files.outputs.files_updated }} ${{ steps.files.outputs.files_created }}  --exit-zero --jobs=0)
    SCORE=$OUTPUT > sed -n 's/^Your code has been rated at \([-0-9.]*\)\/.*/\1/p'
    echo "Pylint finished with score: $SCORE"
    echo 'MESSAGE<<EOF' >> $GITHUB_ENV
    echo  "$OUTPUT"  >> $GITHUB_ENV
    echo 'EOF' >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

What is the command to parse the pylint results which is currently saved as $OUTPUT, and parse the exact score to save it in $SCORE?

```
    OUTPUT=$(pylint ${{ steps.files.outputs.files_updated }} ${{ steps.files.outputs.files_created }}  --exit-zero --jobs=0)
    SCORE=$OUTPUT > sed -n 's/^Your code has been rated at \([-0-9.]*\)\/.*/\1/p'
```

This is the output example, I need to parse the "0.18" part:

```
************* Module src.server
src/server.py:1:0: C0114: Missing module docstring (missing-module-docstring)
src/server.py:5:0: W0401: Wildcard import src.endpoints (wildcard-import)
...
-----------------------------------
Your code has been rated at 0.18/10
```

Comment: `SCORE=$OUTPUT > sed …` will set `SCORE` to the first word of `OUTPUT` and write the stout to a file called `sed` dying in syntax errors by unknown extra words. You probably want to use `SCORE=$(echo "$OUTPUT" | sed …)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `sed`

```
SCORE=$(sed -n '$s/[^0-9]*\([0-9.]*\).*/\1/p' <<< "$OUTPUT")
```

Comment: Your answer is great, but can you update the regex to only parse the score part `0.18`?  Currently, it's parsing the entire thing with `0.18/10`.  Since my goal is to compare the actual score with a threshold in the next step.

Comment: @BillSoftwareEngineer Sure, just remove `/` from the regex. Please check edit

Comment: Works great, thank you so much!

Comment: can you also help me on this question?  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/690810/using-sed-to-parse-score

Comment: I piece of code without any explanation of why the given attempt was wrong and what is done to do it right is not a good answer. Teach the man to fish.

Comment: @Philippos So it deserved a downvote? Erm, okay, great. Enjoy fishing.

Comment: @Philippos It may be an idea to downvote all my answers. They follow the same format and you should follow your moral fishing high ground.

Comment: @HatLess If you turn my comment into an answer, at least copy the explanation along.