# Using sed to parse % score

Tags: sed

I am trying to parse code coverage for my github ci action, I have everything working but can't parse the coverage % result.  Please help me parse the % score for code coverage, I can't get the regex to work:

Command

```
name: Pytest Coverage
on:
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main, dev ]
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Set up Python 3.10
      uses: actions/setup-python@v2
      with:
        python-version: "3.10"
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: |
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install flake8 pytest pytest-cov
        if [ -f requirements.txt ]; then pip install -r requirements.txt; fi
    - name: Build coverage file
      run: |
        pytest --cache-clear --cov=src tests/ > pytest-coverage.txt
    - name: Comment coverage
      uses: coroo/pytest-coverage-commentator@v1.0.2
    - name: Get Coverage %
      run: |
        LAST_LINE=$(tail -4 pytest-coverage.txt)
        LAST_LINE=$(head -n 1 <<< "$LAST_LINE")
        echo "target line is $LAST_LINE"
        COVERAGE=$(sed -n '$s/.*?\([0-9]+\)%.*/\1/p' <<< "$LAST_LINE")
        echo "overall coverage is $COVERAGE"
```

$LAST_LINE is

```
TOTAL                                               2401   1538    36%
```

$COVERAGE is currently blank, expected output:

```
36%
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `sed`

```
COVERAGE=$(sed 's/.*[[:space:]]\([0-9]\+%\)/\1/' <<< "$LAST_LINE")
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove everything until the last blank character (space or tab):

```bsh
$ sed 's/.*[[:blank:]]//' file
36%
```

Use `awk` to print the last whitespace-delimited field:

```bsh
$ awk '{ print $NF }' file
36%
```

Or, as part of your code (assuming only one line starts with the string `TOTAL`

```bsh
COVERAGE=$( sed -n 's/^TOTAL.*[[:blank:]]//p' pytest-coverage.txt )
```

This extracts the percentage directly from the `pytest-coverage.txt`, without having to call `head` or `tail`.

Answer (score 2):

Remove all the non-space characters plus a space character till the end :

```
echo "$LAST_LINE" | sed ':a s/^[^ ]* //;ta'
```

---

`grep` which know `o` option (such as `gnu grep`) :

```
echo $LAST_LINE | grep -o '[0-9]*%'
```